# Calculate sum from number type input fields by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

today I have a question about calculating summation with js.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
  //handler to trigger sum event
  $(".txt").each(function() {

    $(this).keyup(function(){
      calculateSum();
    });
  });

});

function calculateSum() {

  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".txt").each(function() {

    //add only if the value is number
    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }

  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Qty1 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty1"/><br>
Qty2 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty2"/><br>
Qty3 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty3"/><br>
Qty4 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty4"/><br>
Qty5 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty5"/><br>
Qty6 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty6"/><br>
Qty7 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty7"/><br>
Qty8 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty8"/><br>
<br><br>
Total : <span id="sum">0</span><br>
```

This code only works when I input numbers directly in input fields. However, when I click on up-down arrows in input fields, the js code seems not working. How I can fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: change an event from keyup to input: $(this).on('input', function () { --- })

Comment: I got a new problem, how to make my summation calculation work when input fields already had `value` attribute? For instance, I set all my input fields attribute `value="5"` then when I run the program the number 40 should be displayed as summation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changing the element value using the arrow symbols [*change*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event is fired.

Instead of *keyup* try with [***`input`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event.

> The input event fires when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element has been changed.

**Change:**

```
$(this).keyup(function(){
```

**To:**

```
$(this).on('input',function(){
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
  //handler to trigger sum event
  $(".txt").each(function() {

    $(this).on('input',function(){
      calculateSum();
    });
  });

});

function calculateSum() {

  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".txt").each(function() {

    //add only if the value is number
    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }

  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Qty1 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty1"/><br>
Qty2 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty2"/><br>
Qty3 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty3"/><br>
Qty4 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty4"/><br>
Qty5 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty5"/><br>
Qty6 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty6"/><br>
Qty7 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty7"/><br>
Qty8 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty8"/><br>
<br><br>
Total : <span id="sum">0</span><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event handler for `change` event too.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
  //handler to trigger sum event
  $(".txt").each(function() {

    $(this).on('keyup change', function (){
      calculateSum();
    });
  });

});

function calculateSum() {

  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".txt").each(function() {

    //add only if the value is number
    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }

  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Qty1 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty1"/><br>
Qty2 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty2"/><br>
Qty3 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty3"/><br>
Qty4 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty4"/><br>
Qty5 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty5"/><br>
Qty6 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty6"/><br>
Qty7 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty7"/><br>
Qty8 : <input class="txt" type="number" name="qty" id="qty8"/><br>
<br><br>
Total : <span id="sum">0</span><br>
```